# Force menu to inflate before custom method call

Tags: java, android

This issue is giving me nightmares :(
Please consider the following code snippet:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        mMenu = menu;
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    protected void updateActionBar() {
        mMenu.findItem(R.id.action_some).setVisible(state); <---------------- mMenu is null
    }
}
```

BaseActivity.java

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ...

        updateActionBar(); <---------------- This causes crash

    }

    protected abstract void updateActionBar();
}
```

**Problem**

After debugging, I found that dynamic dispatch of `updateActionBar()` happens before call to `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`. Hence, `Menu`inflation is kind of delayed and `mMenu` is not updated.

**Question**

How do I make sure that `mMenu` gets populated before call to `updateActionBar()`?

Note: For sake of focusing on the core problem and improve readability, I have pasted only portion of code that causes crash.

Comment: Try moving updateActionBar(); to onResume();

Comment: I can't do it. `updateActionBar()` is being called inside a listener and moving the whole listener inside `onresume` doesn't make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I make sure that mMenu gets populated before call to updateActionBar()?

Call `updateActionBar()` sometime later, such as in an override of `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` in `BaseActivity`.

> updateActionBar() is being called inside a listener and moving the whole listener inside onresume doesn't make sense

*Where* the listener is does not matter. *What event you are listening for* matters. Apparently, you are using a listener for some event that can occur before `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`. That will not work. Either:

- Choose a different event, or
- Do not register the listener until at least `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` has been called, or
- If the event is triggered, and `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` has not been called, instead of actually doing your work, set a `boolean` value (e.g., `needToDoMenuStuff`) to `true`, and then do that work in `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) I am making call to query inventory to check what items user owns and update the UI accordingly. UpdateActionBar() is being called after the query inventory work is done. Ideally, Ui should be updated just after call to inventory is finished. Otherwise, we might delay updating UI and users will be like: "I have bought this item and still it is asking me to rebuy it"

Comment: @Greengoblin: Then my second and third bullets are your primary options, where the second bullet becomes more like "don't make the call to query inventory until at least `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` has been called".

Comment: It boils down to calling query inventory inside `onPrepareOptionsMenu` until and unless we have some kind of listener to know when `onPrepareOptionsMenu` gets called, right?

Comment: @Greengoblin: Um, well, you know when `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` is called by implementing `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`. :-)

Comment: My bad. So, if call to query inventory is delayed until `onPrepareOptionsMenu` is triggered, then won't there be delay in UI updating if query inventory call is time costly, as we are doing query inventory calls in background thread?

Comment: @Greengoblin: `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` should be called fairly quickly after `onCreate()`.

Comment: onPrepareOptionsMenu() would be called quickly. And it would update the Action bar quickly too. But if we make call to query inventory inside onPrepareOptionsMenu() and query inventory call takes sometime, then the UI would be updated after sometime. How all this will be perceived by user?

Comment: @Greengoblin: "How all this will be perceived by user?" -- it will be perceived about the same as if you update the inventory from `onCreate()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Now I have got few options to explore. I will see what option fits the best in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might serve you well:

```
final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourLayout); // might not be linearLayout
ViewTreeObserver vto = layout.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        // Code to be executed after layout complete. (updateActionBar)
    }
});
```